# Racket pattern matching of lists

Tags: list, pattern-matching, racket, ellipsis

I am trying to do pattern matching with lists, but for some reason I get an unexpected match when I do the following:

```
> (define code '(h1 ((id an-id-here)) Some text here))
> (define code-match-expr '(pre ([class brush: python]) ...))
> (match code
    [code-match-expr #t]
    [_ #f])
#t
```

**Question:** Why does `code` match `code-match-expr`?

## Practical use-case

I tried this in the Racket REPL, because I actually want to solve another practical problem: using Pollen's pygments wrapping functions to highlight code, which will be output as HTML later on. For this purpose I wrote the following code, where the problem occurs:

```
(define (read-post-from-file path)
  (Post-from-content (replace-code-xexprs (parse-markdown path))))

(define (replace-code-xexprs list-of-xexprs)
  ;; define known languages
  (define KNOWN-LANGUAGE-SYMBOLS
    (list 'python
          'racket
          'html
          'css
          'javascript
          'erlang
          'rust))
  ;; check if it matches for a single language's match expression
  ;; if it mathces any language, return that language's name as a symbol
  (define (get-matching-language an-xexpr)
    (define (matches-lang-match-expr? an-xexpr lang-symbol)
      (display "XEXPR:") (displayln an-xexpr)
      (match an-xexpr
        [`(pre ([class brush: ,lang-symbol]) (code () ,more ...)) lang-symbol]
        [`(pre ([class brush: ,lang-symbol]) ,more ...) lang-symbol]
        [_ #f]))

    (ormap (lambda (lang-symbol)
             ;; (display "trying to match ")
             ;; (display an-xexpr)
             ;; (display " against ")
             ;; (displayln lang-symbol)
             (matches-lang-match-expr? an-xexpr lang-symbol))
           KNOWN-LANGUAGE-SYMBOLS))

  ;; replace code in an xexpr with highlightable code
  ;; TODO: What happens if the code is in a lower level of the xexpr?
  (define (replace-code-in-single-xexpr an-xexpr)
    (let ([matching-language (get-matching-language an-xexpr)])
      (cond [matching-language (code-highlight an-xexpr matching-language)]
            [else an-xexpr])))

  ;; apply the check to all xexpr
  (map replace-code-in-single-xexpr list-of-xexprs))

(define (code-highlight language code)
  (highlight language code))
```

In this example I am parsing a markdown file which has the following content:

````
# Code Demo

```python
def hello():
    print("Hello World!")
```
````

And I get the following `xexpr`s:

1.

```
(h1 ((id code-demo)) Code Demo)
```

2.

```
(pre ((class brush: python)) (code () def hello():
    print("Hello World!")))
```

However, none of those match for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` is syntax and does not evaluate the pattern. Since `code-match-expr` is a symbol it will bind the whole expression (result of evaluating `code`) to the variable `code-match-expr` and evaluate the rest of the expressions as the pattern matches. The result will always be `#t`.

Notice that the second pattern, the symbol `_`, is the **same pattern**. It also matches the whole expression, but `_` is special in the way that it does not get bound like `code-match-expr` does.

It's important that your defined variable `code-match-expr` is never used, but since the `match` binds a variable with the same name your original binding will be shadowed in the consequent of the `match`.

Code that works as you intended might look like:

```scm
(define (test code)
  (match code 
    [`(pre ([class brush: python]) ,more ...) #t]
    [_ #f]))

(test '(h1 ((id an-id-here)) Some text here))
; ==> #f

(test '(pre ((class brush: python))))
; ==> #t

(test '(pre ((class brush: python)) a b c))
; ==> #t
```

As you see the pattern `,more ...` means **zero or more** and what kind of brackets is ignored since in Racket `[]` is the same as `()` and `{}`.

**EDIT**

You still got it a little backwards. In this code:

```
(define (matches-lang-match-expr? an-xexpr lang-symbol)
  (display "XEXPR:") (displayln an-xexpr)
  (match an-xexpr
    [`(pre ([class brush: ,lang-symbol]) (code () ,more ...)) lang-symbol]
    [`(pre ([class brush: ,lang-symbol]) ,more ...) lang-symbol]
    [_ #f]))
```

When a pattern is macthed, since `lang-symbol` is unquoted it will match **anything** atomic and be bound to that as a variable in that clause. It will have **nothing** to do with the bound variable by the same name as a `match` does not use variables, it creates them. You return the variable. Thus:

```
(matches-lang-match-expr? '(pre ([class brush: jiffy]) bla bla bla) 'ignored-argument)
; ==> jiffy
```

Here is something that does what you want:

```
 (define (get-matching-language an-xexpr)
    (define (get-language an-xexpr)
      (match an-xexpr
        [`(pre ([class brush: ,lang-symbol]) (code () ,more ...)) lang-symbol]
        [`(pre ([class brush: ,lang-symbol]) ,more ...) lang-symbol]
        [_ #f]))
    (let* ((matched-lang-symbol (get-language an-xexpr))
           (in-known-languages (memq matched-lang-symbol KNOWN-LANGUAGE-SYMBOLS)))
      (and in-known-languages (car in-known-languages))))
```

Again.. `match` abuses quasiquote to something completely different than creating list structure. It uses them to match literals and capture the unqoted  symbols as variables.

Comment: I have a questions regarding this: (1) When I enter `\`(pre ([class brush: python]) 1)` into a Racket shell it prints out `'(pre ((class brush: python)) 1)`. Is that because the expression is evaluated? Otherwise it would seem that the backtick only introduces another list and I don't get why backtick would create something other than a list like single quote. (2) How could I store there ````` expressions in a `hash` for example? Racket tells me that `more` is not defined when I try to do it. I guess using `more` in the match will lead to it being bound and no error, but I have many of those.

Comment: @Zelphir It's the crazy way `#lang racket` visualizes values. Instead of displaying the value it became it displays an expression that would evaluate to that value. So `\`(some thing)` evaluates to `(some thing)` but racket displayes `'(some thing)` because if you evaluate that it should become the same value `(some thing)` which it of course will still display as `'(some thing)`. The quasiquote `\` ` is not difference from `'` unless you use unquote (`,`). Try evaluating `\`(a b ,(+ 1 2))` then evaluate that again.

Comment: Your code works for me in the Racket REPL, but when I try to put it into code, somehow I still get always match or always false depending on how I try it. Could you take a look at it? I'd put it as an edit for practical use case into the question. If you think I should rather make a new question, I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: @Zelphir Just add it to the bottom of your question as an edit and I'll have look at it.

Comment: I have multiple programming languages which I need to match against and I am filling them in with `,lang-symbol` instead of writing `python` there, where `lang-symbol` is an element out of a `(list python racket css)` for example. I'll add the code to the question, maybe it's just something I am overlooking.

Comment: That last paragraph about `match` using quasiquote differently made it clearer for me, thanks, very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're clear what it is you are matching. In Racket x-expressions, attribute names are symbols but the values are strings. So the expression you're matching would be something like `(pre ([class "brush: js"])) ___)` -- *not* `(pre ([class brush: js]) ___)`.

To match that string and extract the part after `"brush: "`, you could use a `pregexp` match pattern. [Here is a snippet that Frog uses to extract the language to give to Pygments](https://github.com/greghendershott/frog/blob/master/frog/enhance-body.rkt#L37-L49):

```
(for/list ([x xs])
  (match x
    [(or `(pre ([class ,brush]) (code () ,(? string? texts) ...))
         `(pre ([class ,brush]) ,(? string? texts) ...))
     (match brush
       [(pregexp "\\s*brush:\\s*(.+?)\\s*$" (list _ lang))
        `(div ([class ,(str "brush: " lang)])
              ,@(pygmentize (apply string-append texts) lang
                            #:python-executable python-executable
                            #:line-numbers? line-numbers?
                            #:css-class css-class))]
       [_ `(pre ,@texts)])]
    [x x])))
```

(Here `pygmentize` is a function defined in other Frog source code; it's a wrapper around running Pygments as a separate process and piping text between it. But you could substitute another way of using Pygments or any other syntax highlighter. That's N/A for your question about `match`. I mention it just so that doesn't become a distraction and another embedded question. :))

Comment: This answer corrects my wrong match case expressions and shows how to further process the matched language, but I can only accept one answer. Nevertheless +1 : )